# Connecting to Graph API for education application permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

I am trying to create a flow process to automate creating CSV files which contains the student, teacher assignment, submissions, and submission outcomes. I have registered an app in Azure AD and I can connect to this fine via PowerShell with delegate permissions and see all of the data I need.

However, when I try to connect with application permissions `EduAdministration.Read.All`, `EduAssignments.Read.All` and `EduRoster.Read.All`,  I can only see basic Class and Student information. So calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/education/classes` works but calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/education/classes/CLASSID/assignments` does not (I get a "Resource not found for the segment 'assignments'").

As I have an admin account which is a member of the CLASSID team, I can see all of this information if running from graph explorer with delegated permissions.

So, is there something else I need to do to get the application `.Read.All` permissions working or are there a tutorial of how to connect to graphs with Flow using delegated permissions?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things going on here:

**"Resource not found for the segment 'assignments'" Error**

You're receiving this error because you're attempting to call the Assignments endpoint in v1.0. [Assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/educationassignment?view=graph-rest-beta&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0) is still in Beta, so you need to use `/beta`, not `/v1.0`.

2. Once you get past the segment error, you will still have a permissions issue. The Assignments endpoint [only supports Delegated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/educationassignment-get?view=graph-rest-beta) scopes. The inverse is true for Classes which [only return limited information using Delegated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/educationclass-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) scopes. In order to call both endpoints, you'll want to have two separate tokens (one delegated, one application):

   - For `/education/classes/{id}`, use the Application scope `EduRoster.Read.All`.
   - For `/education/classes/{id}/assignments/`, use the Delegated scope `EduAssignments.Read`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I am going to give this a try today. Does that mean that the Edu.Assignments.Read.All application permission is not operational yet?

Comment: I believe so. I'm not aware of any endpoints using `Edu.Assignments.Read.All` at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @MarcLaFleur. Are you aware of a roadmap / place I can subscribe to / check when Assignments application permissions would become supported?